# .NET Framework on Azure Function Apps V4 (dotnet-isolated): ConfigurationManager not working

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to migrate some functionality of a legacy .NET Framework over to Azure Function Apps V4 using dotnet-isolated. I can trigger the application, however the app settings and connection strings defined in the Azure Portal are not available through `ConfigurationManager`. Other parts of this application are hosted on App Services and `ConfigurationManager` works fine there.

There's a lot of information available about `IConfiguration` and `local.settings.json`, however that's not what I can use. There's a lot of code depending on `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, which need to keep working as-is. One example is EF6, but also other custom code.

I've defined the app settings and connection strings in the Azure Portal. I can see these as environment variables in the Kudu "Environment" view, like this:

- `APPSETTING_my_setting="myvalue"`
- `SQLAZURECONNSTR_my_connection_string="foo=bar"`

I somehow would've expected for this to "just work", but it doesn't. Am I holding it wrong, or what can I do to convince `ConfigurationManager` to use these settings?

Comment: Azure Functions runs on .NET Core, not .NET Framework. .NET 5 and later .NET *Core* 5 and later, not .NET Framework. Even if you can change the runtime to .NET Framework, it's probably a far better option to migrate to .NET 6 or later. A *serverless* application is very different from a web app, and ASP.NET was simply not built for such an environment, unlike ASP.NET Core. You'll have to make changes to your application no matter what

Comment: While you may be able to use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` compatibility package from NuGet, you won't get access to environment variables. ConfigurationManager only works with `web.config` files and never handled other config sources. You'll have to write a *LOT* of code to get your .NET Old code to run on .NET Core, just to get what's already available out of the box

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This very application runs on .NET Framework and I have no interest in porting it at this point. .NET Framework support is official and released last September of the v4 isolated model: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/generally-available-azure-functions-net-framework-support-in-the-isolated-worker-model/.

Comment: In that case you should be able to use ConfigurationManager to read `web.config` files. That class never worked with environment variables. You'll have to use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to read the values directly

Comment: *Or* you could add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to your application. The package targets .NET Standard 2.0 which means it works on .NET Framework 4.8 too. This would allow you to use any of Azure's configuration services (settings files, env variables, Azure App Configuration). The env variables you tried to use [are explicitly created for the Configuration middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#connection-string-prefixes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to achieve this with configuration builders; a feature introduced with .NET 4.7. I'm using the environment configuration builder to achieve the same behaviour as with a regular App Service. Note the following code only works for SqlAzure type connection strings, but can easily be adjusted to support all connection string types.

Project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Configuration file (`App.config`):

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </configSections>
    <configBuilders>
        <builders>
            <add name="AppSetting" prefix="APPSETTING_" stripPrefix="true" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
            <add name="SqlAzure" prefix="SQLAZURECONNSTR_" stripPrefix="true" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
        </builders>
    </configBuilders>
    <connectionStrings configBuilders="SqlAzure">
        <add name="my_connection_string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings configBuilders="AppSetting">
        <add name="my_setting" value="" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How does this make ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings work from within a v4 Azure Function?  I'm trying to push legacy code to an Azure Function and can't really rewrite how the entire codebase handles configuration.  I added a Web.config to my function but that didn't change the behavior.

Comment: As the output type is `Exe`, you'll need a `App.config` configuration file. Azure sets the specified connection strings as environment variables and `App.config` picks up these environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The Values which are set in the `local.settings.josn` are available as Environment Variables.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

We can read either by using the `EnvironmentVariable` or from the `IConfiguration`.

***Using EnvironmentVariable:***

```cs
 string? my_setting = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_setting");
 string? my_connection_string = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_connection_string");
```

***My `Function1.cs` file:***

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConfigManager14June
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {         

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("CustomHeader", "CustomValue");
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            string? my_setting = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_setting");
            string? my_connection_string = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_connection_string");

            string responseBody = "my_setting - " + my_setting + " , my_connection_string - " + my_connection_string;

            response.WriteString(responseBody);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

***Using IConfiguration:***

```cs
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public Function1(IConfiguration myconfig)
{    
    _configuration = myconfig; ;
}
string my_setting = _configuration["my_setting"];
string my_connection_string = _configuration["my_connection_string"];
```

***OR***

If set under ConnectionString

```cs
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "my_connection_string1": "foo=bar"
  }
```

then read it as,

```cs
string myConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("my_connection_string1");
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Great explanation of how to get the connection string in general. However my question specifically mentions that I don't want to use `IConfiguration`, which is what your answer is using.

Comment: Have you tried with `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Comment: None of this is needed if ASP.NET Core is used, as environment variables prefixed with `DOTNET_` are included in the configuration out of the box. It's also possible to register custom prefixes. There's no need to bypass the Configuration middleware with `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Answer (score -1):

`ConfigurationManager` has never been driven by environment variables, and supports the `.config` XML configuration pattern. You still have that in App Service, in that it has a filesystem where those files can be placed in the relative location that (ASP.)NET expects, but it has no relationship to the App Service configuration collection. I suppose if you are familiar with IIS on-premises you might imagine that the configuration UI would be a view onto this XML configuration file, but that isn't the case anymore, App Service configuration is distinct and is expressed to the application as environment variables.

Comment: 1. So with App Services the configuration is defined on a higher level from my `Web.config`, similar to `machine.config`? And that configuration then takes precedence? -- 2. And then, Function Apps don't provide this inheritance structure? -- 3. So to make `ConfigurationManager` work, I need something custom to read the environment variables, e.g. config builders?

Comment: @Bouke - Did you get a chance to look into the posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76470988/19648279).